# I am trying to sum up a list but getting syntax error in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to sum up a list but getting syntax error in Python

```
a = sum (array) 
        ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator
```

Comment: Remove the space after `sum`.

Comment: The error is somewhere else in your code. Please show the rest.